# OSQL TO SQLCMD Conversion

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sqlcmd, osql

I am trying to convert OSQL comamnd to SQLCMD as below.
The OSQL command is working fine,but converted SQLCMD is throwing below error, Please help.

Original OSQL:

```
osql.exe -S TestDB -E -d TestDB -Q EXIT("Declare @ExecutionResult int  EXEC dbo.p_SP @ExecutionId='test', @ExecutionResult=@ExecutionResult OUTPUT select @ExecutionResult") 2>&1
```

Converted SQLCMD:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:TestDB -E -d TestDB -Q EXIT("Declare @ExecutionResult int  EXEC dbo.p_SP @ExecutionId='test', @ExecutionResult=@ExecutionResult OUTPUT select @ExecutionResult") 2>&1
```

SQLCMD Error: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: 'Declar... '-?' for help.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Probably not your problem, but it would help if you put semi-colons after each statement in your multi-statement SQL String, so it's easier to read/parse/understand.

Comment: Don't think you need to specify EXIT and also add some semicolons
sqlcmd -S tcp:TestDB -E -d TestDB -Q "Declare @ExecutionResult int;  EXEC dbo.p_SP @ExecutionId='test', @ExecutionResult=@ExecutionResult OUTPUT; select @ExecutionResult;" 2>&1

Comment: @DanielN Thank you. This resolved the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Check SQLS**Plus on https://www.sqlsplus.com. It can do much better formatting - loke Oracle' SQL*Plus but for SQL Server.